# How much performance increase can I expect from Tensorflow on GPU over CPU?

Tags: tensorflow

I have installed tensorflow-gpu on Linux Mint 18. My graphics card is a GT 740m. The `deviceQuery` and `bandwidthTest` for CUDA and the MNISTsample for cudnn scripts pass (referred [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/#running-binaries) and [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/#verify)).

Tensorflow does use the GPU (e.g. following [these](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#ValidateYourInstallation) instructions works, and memory and processing utilization of the GPU increases when running programes), but the performance is rather… mediocre.

For instance running the script shown on [this site](https://learningtensorflow.com/lesson10/) the GPU is only about twice as fast as the CPU. Certainly a nice improvement, but not "really, really fast", as is stated on the site. Another example: Using vgg16 with Keras to classify 100 images, each about 300x200 pixels takes around 30 seconds.

Is there anything I might do to increase the performance, or can I not expect anything better?

for search queries: slow,

Comment: What matrix size did you try the script with ? The GPU should become way more efficient at high sizes when the O(n^2) transfer to GPU memory becomes negligible in front of the O(n^3) computations required to perform the matrix multiplication.

Comment: @Sunreef up to around 12000. When I tried 15000 the GPU ran out of memory.

Comment: Then it might be due to your GPU not being very performant.  A GT740m is not really meant to be used for tensor computations. Not to mention it's pretty old  and the website you linked to probably uses a much better modern GPU.